# How would I convert a char array to a float and check its range?

Tags: c, arrays, string, floating-point

I am building an application in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 and I have a function that takes in a char array and is supposed to return a single-precision floating point number.

My function:

```
Token aa_func08(char lexeme[]){
    Token t; /* floating point literal Token to be returned */
    double temp; /* floating point value of character array */

    temp = atof(lexeme); /* convert character array to floating point value */
    if ((FLT_MAX - temp <= FLT_EPSILON) || (temp - FLT_MIN <= FLT_EPSILON)) /* floating point value is outside the accepted range */
        return aa_table[ES](lexeme); /* return an error Token */
    t.code = FPL_T; /* set Token code */
    t.attribute.flt_value = (float)temp; /* set Token integer value to floating point literal value */
    return t; /* return floating point literal Token */
}
```

I would like to check the float value compared to the maximum and minimum values for the float data type, and I also need to check the length of the char array.

The output I expect is the following:

If I pass in:

```
1.999999999999999911111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

I expect to get: `2.000000`

If I pass in:

```
999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999.0
```

I expect to get: `99999999999999999999`

If I pass in:

```
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

I expect to get: `0.000000000000000000`

Does anybody know how I can achieve such results, or at least point me in the right direction? Thank you!

**EDIT**

For the first case, the result `2.000000` is represented by a 32-bit float. The other two results are simply the string `lexeme` being truncated to the first 20 characters. So to summarize, if the `lexeme` represents a valid `float`, it is represented as a float, but if `lexeme` represents an invalid `float` (out of range, missing numbers after decimal point, etc.) then the first 20 characters of `lexeme` are what I return (not an actual `float`).

Comment: What are `FLT_MAX` and `FLT_MIN`?

Comment: I would consider looking at sscanf. Also check out the [LOLCODE implementation.](https://github.com/justinmeza/lci/blob/master/tokenizer.c)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice They are the constants defined in float.h for the maximum and minimum floating point values.

Comment: What do you get compared to what you expect? For cases 1 and 3 I get your expected results. For case 2 I get +INF as it exceeds FLT_MAX. Your expected output for case #2 doesn't make sense. You do understand the difference between `float` and `double` and the inherent imprecision of both?

Comment: @uesp I forgot to clarify that case 1 is represented by a `float`, but case 2 and case 3 are simply `lexeme` truncated to 20 characters.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to give this a read: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Specifically you are not going to get "99999999999999999999", or 20 digits of precision out of a float type (or even out of a double).  Second depending on how you convert the values you are likely to get 1E-83 for "0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001".  You might also want to take a look at [IEEE Floading Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)

Your examples do not match your goals, suggesting that one or the other will lead to disappointment.  If you need to convert a string to a 32 bit float type you will need to stick to the limitations of that format.  If you need the precision (and behavior) your examples describe you will likely need to write some sort of custom numeric type.

Comment: I realize that. Basically in the case of `99999999999999999999` and `0.000000000000000000` the result I'm expecting is actually a string representation of the float value, not an actual float value.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like OP's goal is to check that the number fits in a `float` *range* by using a string to `double` conversion and then testing limits.

The limit tests are ineffective.  Wrong use of `FLT_EPSILON` and `FLT_MIN`.

Suggest simply comparing the `double` to +/-FLT_MAX.

```
volatile double d = atof(lexeme);
if ((d > FLT_MAX) || (d < -FLT_MAX)) {
  return aa_table[ES](lexeme); 
}
t.code = FPL_T; 
t.attribute.flt_value = (float) d;
```

Unclear as how OP would like to handle NaN.

---

[Edit] Now see OP also wants to limit input to 20 `char`.  Suggest:

```
char buf[20+1];
strncpy(buf, lexeme, 20);
buf[20] = '\0';
volatile double d = atof(buf);
...
```

The limit tests still make sense as input could be `1.0e100`, or beyond `FLT_MAX`.

Comment: Where does your variable f come from?

Comment: @Benjamin C. Huskisson-Snider  Sorry, `f` was left over from earlier answer.  Answer updated.